# Remove support for intra word emphasis from PHP Markdown

Tags: php, regex, markdown

I'm trying to modify PHP Markdown to implement 2 out of the [3 changes Jeff Attwood suggested](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/12/responsible-open-source-code-parenting.html), namely, enabling return based line breaks and removing support for intra word emphasis.

I was able to do the first quite easily learning from [How to treat single newline as real line break in PHP Markdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092966/how-to-treat-single-newline-as-real-line-break-in-php-markdown), but I'm finding the second very difficult to implement. There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380310/i-need-help-modifying-a-regular-expression-for-php-markdown) on SO that deals with it, but since I don't really understand regexes yet, I don't know how to implement the given solution.

What modification do I need to make to [Michel Fortin's PHP Markdown](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/) to turn off intra word emphasis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer later by digging inside PHP Markdown Extra.

```
protected $em_relist = array(
    ''  => '(?:(?<!\*)\*(?!\*)|(?<!_)_(?!_))(?=\S|$)(?![\.,:;]\s)',
    '*' => '(?<=\S|^)(?<!\*)\*(?!\*)',
    '_' => '(?<=\S|^)(?<!_)_(?!_)',
    );
protected $strong_relist = array(
    ''   => '(?:(?<!\*)\*\*(?!\*)|(?<!_)__(?!_))(?=\S|$)(?![\.,:;]\s)',
    '**' => '(?<=\S|^)(?<!\*)\*\*(?!\*)',
    '__' => '(?<=\S|^)(?<!_)__(?!_)',
    );
protected $em_strong_relist = array(
    ''    => '(?:(?<!\*)\*\*\*(?!\*)|(?<!_)___(?!_))(?=\S|$)(?![\.,:;]\s)',
    '***' => '(?<=\S|^)(?<!\*)\*\*\*(?!\*)',
    '___' => '(?<=\S|^)(?<!_)___(?!_)',
    );
```

to this:

```
protected $em_relist = array(
    ''  => '(?:(?<!\*)\*(?!\*)|(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_])_(?!_))(?=\S|$)(?![\.,:;]\s)',
    '*' => '(?<=\S|^)(?<!\*)\*(?!\*)',
    '_' => '(?<=\S|^)(?<!_)_(?![a-zA-Z0-9_])',
    );
protected $strong_relist = array(
    ''   => '(?:(?<!\*)\*\*(?!\*)|(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_])__(?!_))(?=\S|$)(?![\.,:;]\s)',
    '**' => '(?<=\S|^)(?<!\*)\*\*(?!\*)',
    '__' => '(?<=\S|^)(?<!_)__(?![a-zA-Z0-9_])',
    );
protected $em_strong_relist = array(
    ''    => '(?:(?<!\*)\*\*\*(?!\*)|(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_])___(?!_))(?=\S|$)(?![\.,:;]\s)',
    '***' => '(?<=\S|^)(?<!\*)\*\*\*(?!\*)',
    '___' => '(?<=\S|^)(?<!_)___(?![a-zA-Z0-9_])',
    );
```

does the job perfectly.